# Angular 2 - open external domain pages in router outlet

Tags: angular

Is there any way to open external domain pages in router outlet?

I already know that it is possible to use window.location.href, but this is going to change the whole page and not only the place (router outlet) i want it to be displayed.

The fact of the matter is: i need to open pages from other sites inside my Angular2 app, in specific locations (router outlets).